# Drupal sending mail issue

Tags: php, email, drupal-7

My problem begins when I had to add a single landing page to an existing Drupal website. I've never worked with this CMS, so I just created a folder for this page in the root folder and put all the content there.

Then it appeared that I need to send mail from this page after submitting a form there. As I understood I can't use drupal_mail() function there, so I tried something like that:

```
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But that gave me no result.

Then I installed SMTP auth module for Drupal and tried to send mail, but again I had no result. However, test messages from SMTP module have been sent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\n";
    $headers .= "From: $email" . "\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To:: $email" . "\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no result.

Comment: can you show me your code where are you using the mail function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosts require you to use an additional parameter, -f, to send mail.

Try:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f".$email);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but mail still doesn't work.